# PostgreSQL: Remove rows from a table using id's

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, primary-key

I have a bill table with id as the pk and a billno column which I should remove duplicates from

**total rows (62924)**

`select count(billno) from bill`

**unique billno (59704), so need to remove 3220 rows**

`select count(distinct billno) from bill`

**query to get the duplicates (3220)**

```
select count(*) from bill
    WHERE bill.billno IN (SELECT billno
                   FROM bill
                   GROUP BY billno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND bill.company_code like '1'
```

However when I remove duplicates by id, the total does not tally :-

**count after remove duplicated rows (61385) => SHOULD GET 59704 here..**

```
select count (*) from bill
where bill.id not in
(
select id from bill
    WHERE bill.billno IN (SELECT billno
                   FROM bill
                   GROUP BY billno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND bill.company_code like '1'
)
```

Can I know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be removing *all* duplicate rows.  If you want a result set with no duplicates, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (billno) b.*
from bill b
order by billno, id desc;
```

This returns the row for each bill that has the highest `id`.

I'm not sure why your query filters on the company.  The question mentions nothing about that filtering.

Comment: I noticed the duplicates had different company_code '1' and '9', hence I opted to retain the higher company_code.

If i were to use this logic on your query, I have to ```order by billno, company_code desc``` right?

Comment: @Pavitran . . . Yes, you would include the company code in the `order by`.